# Android's WebView - Downloading file with <p:commandButton/> in jsf is not working

Tags: android, primefaces, webview, jsf-2.2, android-download-manager

My Web Application was built using JSF2.2 and PrimeFaces 5. I have a function where user can download documents. (".pdf", ".csv", ".xls" and ".log")

I created a android webview app and loaded the URL everything works fine except the download functionality . when I access the web URL using desktop browser or Mobile browsers like Chrome, Firefox download is working fine without any issue, file is downloaded successfully.

I tried debugging the app and found the "DownloadListener" is not even invoked on download click.

primefaces button:

```
<p:commandButton id="download" action="#{documents.download()}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d" styleClass="mpzero" ajax="false" update="@form" />
```

java Download:

```
public void download() throws IOException {
        byte[] pdfData = null;
        String fileName = null;
        String docId = "13215466546";
        documents = new Documents();
        pdfData = service.getPdfdoc(docId);
        if (pdfData != null) {
            FileOutputStream f = null;
            try {
                FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
                response.reset();
                response.setContentLengthLong(pdfData.length);
                response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
                response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
                response.addHeader("Expires", "-1");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                fileName = "Doc_" + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + docId;
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".pdf\"");
                OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
                output.write(pdfData);
                output.close();
                facesContext.responseComplete(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                if (f != null)
                    f.close();
            }
        } else {
            //do something
        }
```

Android Webview:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(activity_main);
            WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(webview);
            mywebview.clearCache(true);
            mywebview.clearHistory();
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.removeAllCookies(null);
            cookieManager.flush();

            WebSettings myView = mywebview.getSettings();
            myView.setAllowFileAccess(false);
            myView.setGeolocationEnabled(false);
            myView.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
            myView.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            myView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

            mywebview.loadUrl(url);
            mywebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        }

        private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient implements DownloadListener {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                    long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));
                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                        mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

My application is incomplete due to this download issue . Am I doing anything wrong here, please suggest me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Androids WebView can't read files which are in the response header. We struggled with that too. You need a direct link to the file which would end with .pdf in your case.

Comment: @lastresort we used to only stream the documents from database.  I need to find a work around for my download functionality in java application it seems. Thanks for the information. :)